# Android License response "Respond normally"

Tags: android, android-lvl

I am implementing android license for a paid app. Test response can be set to be “Respond normally”. What is the expected behavior when response is set to “Respond normally”? Do we need to set response to be “Respond normally” when our application is official published?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the response specifications only apply to accounts/emails that have been entered into your "Test Accounts" list, on the publisher edit page.  When you publish your app, genuine licensed apps will receive the proper response, unless those users exist in your Test Accounts list, in which case they will receive the response that you have specified.

The Test Accounts list is for testing how your app will respond when it receives, for example, a "LICENSED" response from the server.  To test how your app will respond when it receives a response of "UNLICENSED", simply change the dropdown item to UNLICENSED, or whichever response you are trying to test.

Also be aware that the server can take a little while to register a test account, and it can also take a little while to unregister one as well.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, i am still not sure what response i would expect when setting to "Respond normally".

Comment: Respond normally means it will evaluate it the way it normally would.  So if you have a license, it responds with "LICENSED", if you don't, it responds with "NOT_LICENSED" etc.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because i was using the same email as of the publisher account. i.e the email address of the tester and that of the publisher account was same.

I added a new email address to tester account and used that account to install and test the application. It worked.